# Handling null values in C# - uploaded excel data sheet to database

Tags: c#, datatable, casting

I'm trying to read in items from a spread sheet into a data table, which can then be uploaded to a database.

The column I'm having issues with has to read in values that are boolean values. However, sometimes the field is empty. Instead of 0's and 1's, I need to store null into this boolean value when the field is empty.

Here is the original line of code:

```
  bool bool2 = Convert.ToBoolean(row["Bool_02"]);
```

This works well when the field isn't empty.
But I can't check if the field is empty first because you can't store null as a boolean value.
I tried making it a nullable value like so:

```
   bool? bool2 = Convert.ToBoolean(row["Bool_02"]);
     if(bool2 != true || false)
       {
          bool2 = null;
       }
```

But I get an error - object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

I have to take the input of the column, check if its empty - if its empty then save null in the bool variable.

How can I do this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow.isnull?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I can't check if the field is empty first because you can't store null as a boolean value.

Sure you can, just check if the field is DBNull before trying to convert it.

```
if(row["Bool_02"] is DBNull) return;
bool bool2 = Convert.ToBoolean(row["Bool_02"]);
```

If you'd like to stuff it in a nullable boolean, you need a ternary.

```
bool? bool2 = row["Bool_02"] is DBNull ? null : Convert.ToBoolean(row["Bool_02"]);
```

Untested, you might need a typecast to `(bool?)` in that ternary for it to compile.

Comment: I was also going to suggest a ternary with a check.  If you want to ensure `bool2` has a value you could instead give `false` as the first option.

Comment: @Klaycon For the ternary expression, I get this error: type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between <null> and bool

Comment: @izzykk, as noted in the answer, try adding a typecast to `bool?` on either the `null` or `Convert.ToBoolean`. I think either should work.

Comment: @Klaycon I saw that recommendation, and I don't think I'm grasping it - are you saying I should cast null to a nullable boolean? Like, Convert.ToNullableBoolean(null)? (as far as I know that feature isn't available in C#) I don't quite understand the tip - I apologize I am new to all of this.

Comment: oh I see, something like this: bool? bool2 = row["Bool_02"] is DBNull ? (bool?)null : Convert.ToBoolean(row["Bool_02"]);

Comment: @izzykk yes, what you just sent looks correct, I'd expect that to compile